# Not getting expected output of a simple C program

Tags: c, if-statement, recursion, iteration, return-value

```
#include<stdio.h>
int Bye(int n);
void main()
{
    int n = 10;
    printf("%d", Bye(n));
}
int Bye(int m)
{
    if (m > 0) {return (m+Bye(m-2));}
}
```

Here, this code outputs 30 upon running on codeblocks or any other c compiler.
According to my expectation, the code should not give out any output, but it gives output of 30.

The reason is that the value of "m" reduces by 2 after every iteration, until when m = 0, the compiler should ignore any statement inside the "if" block because (m > 0). So, when the compiler skips the code block inside "if" statement, then the entire "return" function also gets skipped, which means the "Bye" function will have no return, which means no output or some kind of error.
In short:-

this is what should happen:
10+8+6+4+2+0 => (m>0) => skip return function => no return => no output/error

but instead, this happens:
10+8+6+4+2+0 => (output = 30)

Please explain why is this happening.

Comment: "skipping" return is producing undefined behavior. Add an `else` clause to return a defined value in case `m<=0`

Comment: If `m > 0` is *false*, what do your function return then? You have told the compiler that the function should return an `int` value, which means you *must* return an `int` value. There's no "optional" return or default return value.

Comment: The only exception to the required return is from [the `main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function)... First of all it *must* be declared to return `int`, anything else is invalid. But that's the ***only*** function where you don't need to have an explicit `return` statement. If one is missing, then the compiler will assume it will return `0`.

Comment: Besides being undefined behaviour, what do you even expect to happen? What is supposed to be added to `m` here: `m+Bye(m-2));` if `m-2` is less than 0? You add up some value but do not provide that value. Summing up random values. Besides that, your compiler should have told you about not returning a value from a non-void function. Don't ignore your compiler messages. They are meant to help you.

Comment: If your `Bye` function "skips" the return statement, that just means it returns without any specific return value.  The caller will pick up whatever value happens to be in the return value register (or whereever the return value is placed).  The result is undefined.  It's a severe bug.  So, fix it.  Add an explicit `return` statement, with a return value.  You should have gotten a compile-time warning about this bug.  Don't ignore those warnings.  Fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Bye` function does not return in all branches.

> ```
> int Bye(int m)
> {
>     if (m > 0) {return (m+Bye(m-2));}
> }
> ```

Eventually the recursion will lead to `Bye` being pass a value that is not greater than `0`, and then undefined behavior will be invoked. The return value of your `Bye` function will be indeterminate. It looks like in the event of `m` being less than `0` you want to return `0`. If so, you should state as much explicitly.

```
int Bye(int m)
{
    if (m > 0) {
        return (m + Bye(m-2));
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Ensure you compile with all warnings on.

Style note: `void main() { ... }` may work with your compiler, but prefer `int main(void) { ... }` in modern C.

Comment: You can say thank you on Stack Overflow by marking an answer as accepted if you feel it is a good answer to your question.